# css grid method dragging html elements it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website that currently uses css and html and I am running into the problem where my grid in css is created inside the .middle element, but it is also moving elements inside the neighbouring .header element. To see this, change the first margin value inside of the css to see what happens.

```css
h1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    z-index: -1;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.nav{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding:10px;
    width: 15px;
    left: 48%;
}
.friends{
}
.user-post{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.posts{
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.post:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: grey;
}

.bottom{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
}
.headings{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    right: 0%;
}
.middle{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main_Page.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 id="top">Search Media</h1>
        <div class="nav">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Messages.html">Messages</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Friends</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="user-post">
            <br />
            Create post:<br>
            <textarea id= "create_post"rows="10" cols = "50" name = "post"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </div>
        <div class="friends">
            <h2 id="friend">Friends</h2>
            <h5>Friend1</h5>
            <p>status: active</p>
        </div>
        <div class="posts">
            <div class="post">
                <h3 id="existing_posts">Posts</h3>
                <p><img src="Example.jpg" alt="manchester" width="50" height="50">This is an example of a post. It will need to be boxed and made so that the name of the user goes above
                    the name of the likes and dislikes of the posts are to the left of the post and that the reply and report
                    functionalities are at the bottom right of the posts. It will also need a box around it to show where the post starts and ends.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h3 id="existing_posts">Posts</h3>
                <p>This is a rancdom bit of text for tesxting purposes.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h3 id="existing_posts">Posts</h3>
                <p>This is a rancdom bit of text for tesxting purposes.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <p><a href="#header">Return to top</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
```